# inline anchors with fixed header

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, header

hei,

I'm working with footnotes in a website that has a fixed header and I'm trying to cross-link between the footnote number in text and the footnote text at the bottom of the page, which works fine. But linking back from the footnote text at bottom of the page to the footnote number in text gives me a headache.
I cannot use this style (it introduces a line break, which I don't want).

```
a.anchor{
  display: block; 
  position: relative; 
  top: -125px; 
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Would there be any other way of doing what I'm trying to do?

thanks in advance!

...... 
EDIT: (HERE IS MY CURRENT CODE)

**html:**

intext:

```
<p >some tesst<span ><a class="anchor" id="footnote-027-backlink"></a><a class="_idFootnoteLink" href="#footnote-027">1</a></span> some more text.
```

bottom of the page:

```
<a class="anchor" id="footnote-027"></a>
    <div class="_idFootnote">
        <p class="footnote"><a class="_idFootnoteAnchor" href="#footnote-027-backlink">1</a>footnote text</p>
    </div>
```

css:

```
a.anchor{
  display: block; 
  position: relative; 
  top: -125px; 
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

what this does it it starts a new line right BEFORE the actual footnote, because it's set to display:block but `display: inline`doesn't make any difference. what I want is the line to just continue.

Comment: What do you mean by "headache"? Without HTML etc it's hard to offer much assistance. A clarification of the **exact** issue would be helpful.

Comment: I added some code. is that helpful. I think the explanation is already quite exact.... if u need details: maybe you can tell me which ones EXACTLY you mean ;)

Comment: why not put the `<a class="anchor" id="footnote-027"></a>` inside the footnote div? - http://jsfiddle.net/csa6bqLt/

Comment: because that doesn't have to do anything with the actual problem. the problem is in the intext-footnote-reference not the actual footnote at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Have you put a `href` in **both** the relevant links? At the moment it doesn't look like it?

Comment: yes there is in the code above. both have href

Comment: I really think you're going to have to make a demo of this not working